# how would you know if windows is installed as UEFI or Legacy, in windows 7 compared to windows 8?

Tags: windows-7

how would you know if windows is installed as UEFI or Legacy, in windows 7 compared to windows 8?

I understand that after windows 7, so in windows 8 and windows 10, it can show in msinfo32 under "BIOS Version", it should says "BIOS Mode" , but Windows 7 doesn't have that.

Comment: Does your pc support uefi? Make and model pf PC?

Comment: Start in BIOS. That should tell you conclusively.  It will say UEFI BIOS if supported.

Comment: @John the question didn't ask if UEFI mode is supported.. it is possible to have the UEFI  set to BIOS/Legacy mode, So then UEFI is supported, but Windows could be installed for Legacy/BIOS.  One thing that would show it would be to set the UEFI to  UEFI mode, i.e. not Legacy/BIOS mode, and if it goes into windows then it'd mean windows is installed for UEFI.  ' cos  I suppose maybe UEFI "mode" would only support UEFI windows, and Legacy mode will only support windows as legacy.

Comment: I offered that as a starting point to see if the computer supported UEFI - It may not.  Simple - right?

Comment: Windows doesn’t support being installed in UEFI mode if Compatibility Mode is enabled.

Comment: In order to use UEFI, you have to have secure boot enabled in the BIOS, you cannot switch UEFI and legacy mode without reinstalling windows. If Legacy mode was enabled to install Windows 7 (which is likely the case) and you upgraded windows, then the upgraded version will always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a really good page on that here

https://www.eightforums.com/threads/bios-mode-see-if-windows-boot-in-uefi-or-legacy-mode.29504/

It shows the difference between Windows 7 and Windows 8 msinfo32

You see that Windows 8 had a bunch more info between items "SMBIOS Version" and "Windows Directory", and one of those things is "BIOS Mode".

[image]

And that link shows how you can tell a)from disk management  and b)from a file setupact.log

In disk management, it will label the 100MB partition with EFI if windows is installed as UEFI. And it will label it "system reserved" if windows is installed as legacy.

And also this file here `c:\windows\panther\setupact.log` will say whether EFI or Legacy/BIOS e.g.

```
C:\Windows\Panther>type setupact.log | find /i "detected boot envir"
2022-04-09 02:04:14, Info                  IBS    Callback_BootEnvironmentDetect
: Detected boot environment: BIOS
```

Note- a related thing is how to check if the partition table format is MBR or GPT, which disk management and also diskpart shows. As mentioned on here https://www.howtogeek.com/245610/how-to-check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-and-how-to-convert-between-the-two/

(besides starting the UEFI/BIOS with UEFI enabled and seeing if it goes in!)

Answer (score 2):

Run `msinfo32`. The information is inside the System Summary section,
line "BIOS Mode" :

[image]

In Windows 7 the BIOS Mode may not be specified, which likely
indicates the Legacy BIOS. To be sure, open the file
`C:\Windows\Panther\setupact.log` and search for the string
"Callback_BootEnvironmentDetect: Detected boot environment":

[image]